Maneuvering Speed and load factor at different gross weights/ configurations
Many aircraft POH documents list Maneuvering Speed, and as is appropriate, they include a caveat that this speed is calculated at maximum aircraft gross weight. They then, often, include a second Maneuvering Speed at a lower gross weight, using the fact that at lower gross weights, the maximum available Angle of Attack can produce the same maximum load factor (as defined in the POH), at a lower calibrated airspeed. This is of course true. Load Factor, (G) is Lift / Weight, and there is no Weight variable in the Lift equation.  Maximum allowable Load Factor changes as gross weight changes, yes, but does maneuvering speed?
Load factor, (acceleration or Gs), does not break anything, it is local stress on a piece or section of a structure (like an airframe, or wing), caused by an applied force, which causes that piece or section of the structure to fail. At any airspeed, at the critical AOA, regardless of gross weight, the aircraft aerodynamics will produce the exact same total aerodynamic force, (and therefore the same total lift force). The G's will of course be higher if the gross weight is lower, but the Lift produced, and the forces on the airframe, will be the approximately the same.
There will of course be small changes due to differences in the distribution of the total force - the local forces on various parts of the airframe due to changes in the force distribution pattern. Obviously, burning off all the fuel in the wings spreads the total mass of the aircraft more evenly along the main wing spar, and this reduces the local stress on each point along the spar. (This is why they put tip tanks on aircraft).
As an aside, other things significantly affect this as well. Rolling the aircraft changes the lift distribution pattern, putting higher stress on parts of the up-moving wing than on the downward moving wing. This is why military aircraft have lower rolling G-limits.
So maneuvering speed, (which is ostensibly based on the risk of structurally damaging the airframe due to an inadvertent gust or updraft/downdraft, etc.) causing an AOA excursion close to the maximum critical angle of attack, should be the same, (or nearly the same) at all gross weights. Sure, at a lower gross weight, that same excursion will result in higher G-load, but the aerodynamic force, (F=ma), and the resultant stress on the airframe, will be the same.
here for example is a chart from the F-4E flight manual, that clearly illustrates that Load factor limits are dependent on gross weight.

Why is it a common practice to list a lower maneuvering speed for lower gross weight conditions on GA aircraft POHs?? I was surprised recently to see an You Tube video which mentioned this (not as causal) in the process of analyzing an accident.
Is this done simply based on the mistaken (Appeal to Authority) argument that once the manufacturer or FAA certification authority has defined and published a maximum load factor for an aircraft, that that published load factor must be utilized and respected for all flight conditions and analyses?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Because the maneuvering speed is not calculated to safeguard against pulling the wings off the fuselage (or vice versa depending on how you look at), or to limit the bending load applied to wing spar.  The maneuvering speed is calculated to prevent large heavy items of fixed mass from being ripped off their mountings.  E.g. the main electrical battery, the engine(s), etc.  Limit the G-load, and you limit the stress on these mounting points.
As far as the wing-to-fuselage junction goes, or the bending load applied to the wing spar, adding additional weight to the fuselage obviously cannot be protective, and the maximum G-load that these structures can tolerate clearly decreases if extra weight is added to the fuselage.  But not if extra weight is added to the wingtips.
See also these answers to related ASE questions:
Why does maneuvering speed vary with weight?
How does an aircraft's weight affect the V-n diagram?
G Load during payload drop
What is Vg in this VG diagram?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Imagine the forces on just the engine during a 4g pull-up. We'll assume the engine is at idle for simplicity. The engine is accelerating upwards at 3g just like the rest of the airplane. This requires the airframe to exert a force of four times the weight of the engine to produce this acceleration.
Thus, the force applied to the engine by the airframe is a function only of load factor, and the total weight is irrelevant. If the attachments of the engine to the rest of the airframe are the weakest link, then the maximum load factor is not a function of total weight and the maneuvering speed will increase with gross weight.
This isn't how it has to be in every aircraft. It may be that the some part of the wing is the weakest link. This would manifest as mostly-fixed maximum total force and a decrease in maximum load factor with increased weight, which leads to a maneuvering speed that does not change much with gross weight.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
